# how can I find out what's causing the deadlock in mariadb?

Tags: mariadb, locking

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue in a magento 2 website. It seems that at random times there comes a situation where mariadb seems to go into a deadlock situation and slowly stops serving requests. I end up with a state where every query is stuck in a waiting state. In the end some queries time out, I receive notifications about lock wait timeout exceeded and the queries eventually finish executing.

I'm trying to deduce what's happening and how to solve this but I'm stuck and need some help understanding the cause of this issue.

[image]

During the last deadlock I was able to acquire a full processlist

https://pastebin.com/raw/ZfH9Q5Lg

All queries when ran by themselves one by one finish between 60-150ms from my checks but when this situation occurs they can get stuck for more than 5 minutes in that state so I'm assuming it's a lock preventing the queries from executing.

Any ideas of what the next steps are to detect the offending query causing the bottleneck?

I'm on MariaDB 10.4 on Ubuntu 20.04

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS"
```

```
Server version: 10.4.28-MariaDB-1:10.4.28+maria~ubu2004-log mariadb.org binary distribution
```

Any help is appreciated

```
~$ my_print_defaults  --mysqld
--user=mysql
--pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
--socket=/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
--basedir=/usr
--datadir=/var/lib/mysql
--tmpdir=/tmp
--lc-messages-dir=/usr/share/mysql
--bind-address=0.0.0.0
--key_buffer_size=64M
--max_allowed_packet=1G
--max_connections=300
--query_cache_size=16M
--log_error=/var/log/mysql/error.log
--expire_logs_days=10
--character-set-server=utf8mb4
--collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
--query_cache_size=0
--query_cache_type=0
--query_cache_limit=0
--join_buffer_size=512K
--tmp_table_size=128M
--max_heap_table_size=128M
--innodb_buffer_pool_size=32G
--innodb_buffer_pool_instances=16
--innodb_log_file_size=4G
--optimizer_use_condition_selectivity=1
--optimizer_switch=optimize_join_buffer_size=on
--in_predicate_conversion_threshold=4294967295
--innodb_data_home_dir=/var/lib/mysql/
--innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
--innodb_log_group_home_dir=/var/lib/mysql/
--innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50
--innodb_file_per_table=1
--innodb_log_buffer_size=4M
--performance_schema
--optimizer_switch=rowid_filter=off
--optimizer_use_condition_selectivity=1
--optimizer_search_depth=0
--slow_query_log
--slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
--long_query_time=20.0
--innodb_print_all_deadlocks=1
--lock_wait_timeout=240
--bind-address=0.0.0.0
--sql_mode=
--local-infile=0
--innodb_open_files=4000
--table_open_cache=3000
--table_definition_cache=3000
```

Added result of `show engine innodb status;`

https://pastebin.com/raw/WfrkPQr6

Added result of `sudo gdb --batch --eval-command="set print frame-arguments all"  --eval-command="thread apply all bt full" /usr/sbin/mysqld $(pgrep -xn mysqld)  > mariadbd_full_bt_all_threads.txt`

https://ots.ioweb.gr/?122f27bfb605b627#7GiR2X91LMx7W8k686LFid2eVNvVCnr7ijeHauQMg5e4

Comment: "Stuck in a waiting state" would imply a live lock? A deadlock causes queries to be aborted. `show engine innodb status` will show the result of the current live locks, and the previous deadlock. Can you include "SHOW GLOBAL STATUS" and `my_print_defaults --mysqld`, it may be a tuning issue. Also see [magento stack exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com). I've heard `tx_isolation=READ-COMMITTED` may help.

Comment: I"ve added `my_print_defaults  --mysqld` and I'll try to provide show engine innodb status next time it reoccurs. Regarding tx_isolation=READ-COMMITTED it actually made things worse for me. Instead of the site dropping 1-2 times per day it dropped like 20 in the same day it was changed. I reverted immediately

Comment: `query_cache_size=16M` is a common contention - set this off at runtime with `set global query_cache_size=0` and disable in the configuration file. Interesting disable of `rowid_filter=off`, that would help in large `IN (...)` lists. 10.4.29+ has a number of fixes if that was causing troubles. [log-slow-verbosity=query_plan,explain,innodb](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#log_slow_verbosity) might put some useful query plan info in your slow query log.

Comment: Maybe just try an update. [debug info installed](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/#installing-debug-info-packages-from-mariadbs-debian-or-ubuntu-repository) + [backtrace on running process](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/#getting-backtraces-from-a-running-mysqld-process-with-gdb-on-linux) will form a [good bug](https://jira.mariadb.org) report as all processes stuck is a serious bug.

Comment: I've added the result of `show engine innodb status` and also rowid_filter is set as per adobe's instructions https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/prerequisites/database-server/mysql.html?lang=en

I've adjusted the query_cache_size 

I'm not sure how I can check the backtrace though

Comment: I've installed the debug info tools and I'll try getting the backtrace as well next time it occurs. Installing it forced a restart on the mysql server

Comment: I've also added an example backtrace on running process

Comment: Can you create a [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org) for this? A number of things are waiting on `page_id={m_space = 4747, m_page_no = 40}` however something is blocking it. Thanks for the 10.4.31 update.

Comment: I pretty much had to upgrade it to get the trace but I thought a minor version upgrade won't hurt also. Regarding the bug report, I'd like to create it but I'm not sure how to describe it correctly. I've opened it but I'm not sure if it's a bug or not https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-32033

Comment: Do you think it's a bug or is there a way to detect what the block is so that I can mitigate the situation @danblack

Comment: I think the assessment as bug assessment is fair. I haven't found the connection in the information provided to narrow this down unfortunately. The debugging stack in 10.6 is much friendlier if you are willing to attempt an upgrade. 10.6 also contains some fixes not in earlier versions. [downgrade](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/downgrading-between-major-versions-of-mariadb/) has some not recommended steps.

Comment: Would mysqldump and mysql import work normally if needed to downgrade afterwards? I'm concerned with the compatibility of our current magento version. While on staging environment we use 10.6 without issues, there's always the case that in a production environment it may pose some challenges. 

I've noticed that sometimes there's different information regarding the queries in the dump and may be more informational. Should I post some more dumps as they come?

Comment: yes mysqldump / import should work on magento database. I'd test to be sure. Omit `mysql` database from save/restore. A couple more gdb backtraces could be insightful.

Comment: @danblack I noticed that after setting query_cache_size to 0 the total cpu usage of mysql increased. is there a  rule of setting the proper size ?

Comment: Yes,0 is the correct size :-) The query cache lock is highly contended so unless you have a read only load with expensive queries and probably some other criteria its not recommended, hence default 0.

Comment: I see thanks. I've also been reading on how to reduce the mysql CPU usage, so I've noticed that adding `thread_handling=pool-of-threads` to mitigate the problem of CPU usage actually helps. It reduced the CPU usage by 20%. Is this a good setting or do you think it will increase contention for resources?

Comment: That's a good gain. `show global status` will show the good use of the cache. A cached thread isn't much resources and low contention.

Comment: Are the tables `ENGINE=InnoDB`?  (They should be.)  Do you ever use `LOCK TABLES`?  (You probably should not.)  Is there an index on `sku`?  How much RAM do you have?  (Because of `innodb_buffer_pool_size=32G`, it had better be more than 32GB.)

Comment: Yeah it uses innodb and the server has 128GB RAM, it turns out that all queries are blocked because the rename table query requires an exclusive lock and waits on the earlier select statements while also blocking all later statements. The weird thing is those selects are normally running lightning fast like 70ms or 100ms but in this occasion they take ages